# Subtracting checkbox values from hidden input value using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I've been attempting to add and subtract from a hidden form filed and update screen text based on the values of the checked and unchecked boxes.  I've been able to successfully add up all the checked checkbox values and update the hidden input field using .each.  However, I'm having a heck of a time subtracting values from the total.

The issue I can't seem to avoid is subtracting the value of the first checked box instead of the box I'm actually unchecking.  I tried to reference the box by id but that didn't seem to help.

```
$(document).on("click", ".activities .checkbox-select", function(event){

    //event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("selected");

    //Checks the checkbox
    $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").prop('checked', true);

    var total = parseFloat($("#basePoints").val());
    $(':checkbox:checked.activity').each(function() {

        var activtyValues = 0;
        activtyValues = parseFloat(this.value);

        total += activtyValues;

        //Update the screen value
        $("#calulatedpoint").text(total);

        //Update the hidden value
        $("#calulatedPointsHidden").val(total);
    });     
});

$(document).on("click", ".activities .checkbox-deselect", function(event){

    //Get the checkbox id
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    //event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().removeClass("selected");

    var total = $("#calulatedPointsHidden").val();
    checkedValue = $("input[@id="+id+"]:checked").val();  //It's finding the first checked checkbox value and subtracting that



    total -= checkedValue;

    //Update the screen value
    $("#calulatedpoint").text(total);

    //Update the hidden value
    $("#calulatedPointsHidden").val(total);

    //Unchecks the checkbox
    $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
});
```

Any help figuring out my subtraction issue would be appreciated.  Tips on improving my addition section would be great too.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the html?  I would guess you have multiple checkboxes with the same id which isn't valid.

Comment: Each checkbox is dynamically assigned a unique name and id based on a nested drop-down from a DB.  There is only one of each activity in the table without any duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the defect is here I believe

```
checkedValue = $("input[@id="+id+"]:checked").val();
```

this checkbox is no longer checked, but you are specifying checked in the jquery selector, seems like it would not return any value since you also include id?

also the @ sign is no longer used for attribute selecting, maybe you are using older version of jquery?

```
var checkedValue = $("input[id=" + id + "]").val();
console.log(checkedValue);
```

**EDIT:** *adding possible alternate version, use 1 click event handler*

```
$(document).on("click", ".activities", function(event) {
    // add up all the checked items
    // set/reset the hidden field

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        // update UI for checked item
    } else {
        // update UI for unchecked item
    }
});
```

Comment: I did end up solving my issue by mimicking what I did when I add up the boxes.  I like how you gave an example of combining the check/uncheck functions.  I will have to work towards that as an improvement.  For that I'll give you the credit because that is probably the more efficient way to handle the boxes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my issue by mimicking how I added up the checkbox values.  Because the functions are now almost identical I'll work towards using one function to handle checking and unchecking.  Below is what ended up subtracting the value of the checkbox I was unchecking from my running total.

```
$(document).on("click", ".activities .checkbox-deselect", function(event){

    //event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().removeClass("selected");

    //Unchecks the checkbox
    $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").removeAttr("checked");

    var total = parseFloat($("#basePoints").val());
    $(':checkbox:checked.activity').each(function() {

        var activtyValues = 0;
        activtyValues = parseFloat(this.value);

        total += activtyValues;

    });

    //Update the screen value
    $("#calulatedpoint").text(total);

    //Update the hidden value
    $("#calulatedPointsHidden").val(total);
});
```